# How to change size of SVG circle

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to resize my first SVG circle from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1zekermit/t7jgL9pa/10/), so I made the second, but there is a problem in the animation, the animation is not the same.

HTML:

```
<div class="loader">
    <svg class="circular">
        <circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="8" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
    </svg>
</div>


<div style="margin-top: 50px;" class="loader">
    <svg class="circular">
        <circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="44" fill="none" stroke-width="8" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, svg, circle {
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
.loader {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    zoom: 1;
    background-color: grey;
}
.circular {
    -webkit-animation: rotate 3s linear infinite;
    animation: rotate 3s linear infinite;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}
.path {
    stroke-dasharray: 1, 200;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    -webkit-animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite, color 6s ease-in-out infinite;
    animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite, color 6s ease-in-out infinite;
    stroke-linecap: round;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
    0% {
        stroke-dasharray: 1, 200;
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    50% {
        stroke-dasharray: 89, 200;
        stroke-dashoffset: -35;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dasharray: 89, 200;
        stroke-dashoffset: -124;
    }
}
@keyframes dash {
    0% {
        stroke-dasharray: 1, 200;
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    50% {
        stroke-dasharray: 89, 200;
        stroke-dashoffset: -35;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dasharray: 89, 200;
        stroke-dashoffset: -124;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes color {
    100%, 0% {
        stroke: #d62d20;
    }
    40% {
        stroke: #0057e7;
    }
    66% {
        stroke: #008744;
    }
    80%, 90% {
        stroke: #ffa700;
    }
}
@keyframes color {
    100%, 0% {
        stroke: #d62d20;
    }
    40% {
        stroke: #0057e7;
    }
    66% {
        stroke: #008744;
    }
    80%, 90% {
        stroke: #ffa700;
    }
}
```

How to properly resize it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `stroke-dasharray` property of the `circle` element determine the length of the stroke's dash and the space between two dashes whereas the `stroke-dashoffset` determines the offset at which the stroke's dash starts. Within the `@keyframes` rules these properties are getting modified and thus ends up producing the animation effect. When the circle's radius (and thus the circumference) is changed, these properties (set within the `keyframes`) also have to modified in proportion to the radius.

Since the settings depend on the radius of the circle, I don't think you can keep the same animation (`@keyframe`) settings for both circles. At any time only one of them can work properly.

In the below snippet I have done the changes that are required to make the bigger circle work.

```css
body,
svg,
circle {
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
}
.loader {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  zoom: 1;
  background-color: grey;
}
.circular {
  -webkit-animation: rotate 3s linear infinite;
  animation: rotate 3s linear infinite;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1, 440;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  -webkit-animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite, color 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite, color 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1, 440;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 89, 440;
    stroke-dashoffset: -77;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 89, 440;
    stroke-dashoffset: -272;
  }
}
@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1, 440;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 89, 440;
    stroke-dashoffset: -77;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 89, 440;
    stroke-dashoffset: -272;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes color {
  100%, 0% {
    stroke: #d62d20;
  }
  40% {
    stroke: #0057e7;
  }
  66% {
    stroke: #008744;
  }
  80%,
  90% {
    stroke: #ffa700;
  }
}
@keyframes color {
  100%, 0% {
    stroke: #d62d20;
  }
  40% {
    stroke: #0057e7;
  }
  66% {
    stroke: #008744;
  }
  80%,
  90% {
    stroke: #ffa700;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top: 50px;" class="loader">
  <svg class="circular">
    <circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="44" fill="none" stroke-width="8" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

---

Alternately, if you wish to make the same animation (`@keyframe`) settings work for both the circles at the same time, then you could consider using a `transform: scale` to create the bigger circle instead of manually modifying the radius of the circle. (*But as you can see, the output is not exactly same as modifying the radius and hence I wouldn't really recommend this*).

```css
body,
svg,
circle {
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
}
.loader {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  zoom: 1;
  background-color: grey;
}
.circular {
  -webkit-animation: rotate 3s linear infinite;
  animation: rotate 3s linear infinite;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1, 200;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  -webkit-animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite, color 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite, color 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1, 200;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 89, 200;
    stroke-dashoffset: -35;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 89, 200;
    stroke-dashoffset: -124;
  }
}
@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1, 200;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 89, 200;
    stroke-dashoffset: -35;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 89, 200;
    stroke-dashoffset: -124;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes color {
  100%, 0% {
    stroke: #d62d20;
  }
  40% {
    stroke: #0057e7;
  }
  66% {
    stroke: #008744;
  }
  80%,
  90% {
    stroke: #ffa700;
  }
}
@keyframes color {
  100%, 0% {
    stroke: #d62d20;
  }
  40% {
    stroke: #0057e7;
  }
  66% {
    stroke: #008744;
  }
  80%,
  90% {
    stroke: #ffa700;
  }
}
.loader2 {
  transform: scale(2.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <svg class="circular">
    <circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="8" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
  </svg>
</div>


<div style="margin-top: 100px;" class="loader loader2">
  <svg class="circular">
    <circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="8" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
  </svg>
</div>
```